# Grouping on basis of whether an association is null

Tags: hibernate, jpa, criteria-api

I have a entityA which has optional many to one relationship with entityB.

I want to find the count of entityA is related to entityB and the total count in one query. How do I do that.

For example of instances a1, a2, a3, a4 of type entityA and b1, b2 and b3 of type entityB.

a1 is related to b1. a2 and a3 are related to b2. a4 is not related.

So i want a criteria which will be give me a result

total entities=4
total entities with relation to entityB=3

Answer (score 0):

I can tell that you are abstracting the code quite a bit, but you want something like this.

```
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(EntityA.class);
    criteria.createAlias("entityBList", "entityB")
        .setProjection(Projections.rowCount())
        .add(Restrictions.eq("entityB", 3);
```

Comment: we do not want to add a restriction of entityb=3. We are talking about the count turning out to be 3.

Comment: you need to post more information. what code have you attempted? And how many columns do you want in your result? It is not clear